# Dynamic work rebalancing with custom unbounded source and reader for google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have the following implementation of a custom reader and a custom source:

public class CustomPubsubReader extends UnboundedReader {....}

public class CustomPubsubSource extends UnboundedSource {....}

Going through the documentation, it appears that dynamic work rebalancing is applicable only for bounded sources.

In my case, I see that only 1 worker node is created to read the message from custom source even if the message queue is receiving 1000s of elements/s.

If I used PubsubIO.Read() for example, it would create > 1 worker in this case for a streaming mode.

Is there any way to scale out when using a custom source with Cloud Dataflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `UnboundedSource` may implement `generateInitialSplits` (Dataflow 1.X) or `split` (Dataflow 2.0) to produce multiple readers for a given source.

See the [Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/UnboundedSource.html#split-int-org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions-)  for more details.